# Selected values in a v-for loop of components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I implemented a component that have a select element inside and it is like following more or less:

```html
<!-- child component -->
    <template>
        <b-form-select 
            v-model="selectedProject"
            :options="projects"
            @change="changedValue">
            <template v-slot:first>
                <option :value="null" disabled>-- Please select a project --</option>
            </template>
        </b-form-select>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
        name: 'AllocationItem',
        props: {
            projects: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => [{ value: Number}, { text: String}]
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                selectedProject: null,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changedValue(value) {
                this.selectedProject = value;
            }
        }

    }
    </script>
```

I use this component in a parent componenent where it can be possible add other AllocationItem clicking on a button.

To do that i have used an array where i push a new item every time that there is a click on add button (i don't know if it's the right way...)

Follow parent component code:

```html
<!-- parent component -->
    <template>
        <b-button class="btnAction" @click="addItem()">Add</b-button>
        <b-button class="btnAction" @click="sendAllocation()">Send</b-button>
        <b-row v-for="allocation in resourceItem.allocations" v-bind:key="allocation.id">
            <allocation-item v-bind:projects="projects"></allocation-item>
        </b-row>
    </template>


    <script>
        export default {
        name: 'Management',
        components: {
            AllocationItem
        },
        data() {
            return {
                allocations: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addItem() {
                this.allocations.push(AllocationItem);
            },
            sendAllocation() {
                this.allocations.forEach((allocation) => {
                    // I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE ALL SELECTED VALUE HERE!!!
                });
            },
        },
        created() {
            const dataProjects = this.getProjectsData();
            dataProjects.then(response => {
                this.projects = response.map((item) => {
                    return {value: item.id, text: item.name}
                })
            });
        }
    </script>
```

In my application i have another button, send button, that should be read values selected in all child component (allocation-item).

How can i do to have an array with that selected values?

Thank you in advance to all

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the relationship from your 'Send Button'-component with your parent component. 
You can either:

- Use the $emit() method to propagate data up the component tree to the shared parent component. Then prop it down to the 'Send Button'-component.
- Have a single source of truth by using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). This is a store that keeps all your data in a centralised object.

Perhaps you can provide us with more information on the project structure?

Comment: Thank you @laurensvm, i know both solutions and i'm trying with $emit on change (i don't have vuex in my project).
But i don't understand one thing: "how can i to distinguish $emit from different component?"
For example i can have 3 or 4 (or more) component rendered by v-for loop ...
How can i to distinguish $emit from first component to $emit from second or third component?

Comment: If they're equal components, I don't think you can. But that shouldn't really matter, right?

Comment: sorry @laurensvm but i don't understant. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ask yourself if this component is being used anywhere else but here. If you only use it once, build it into the parent component and your problems are solved.
Otherwise I'd go with @laurensvm's approach of using emit or Vuex.

Comment: thank you for your feedback sebastian. Obviusly i need to use component in more that one part :)

Answer (score 0):

After some researches on google i have founded a solution. I don't know if it the right way but it works fine and it seems clean.

My solution consists to use emit on child component and v-model on parent like show following example.

```html
<!-- child component -->
    <template>
        <b-form-select 
            v-model="selectedProject"
            :options="projects"
            @change="changedValue">
            <template v-slot:first>
                <option :value="null" disabled>-- Please select a project -- 
</option>
            </template>
        </b-form-select>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
        name: 'AllocationItem',
        props: {
            projects: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => [{ value: Number}, { text: String}]
            },
            value: {
                type: Number
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                selectedProject: this.value
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changedValue(value) {
                this.$emit('input', value);
            }
        }

    }
    </script>
```

And on parent using an array variable on v-model. 
Something like this:

```html
<!-- parent component -->
<template>
    <b-container>
            <b-row>
                    <b-button class="btnAction" variant="success" @click="addItem(index)">Add</b-button>
                    <b-button class="btnAction" @click="sendAllocation(index)">Send</b-button>
            </b-row>
            <b-row v-for="(allocation, index) in resourceItem.allocations" v-bind:key="allocation.id">
                <allocation-item v-bind:projects="projects" v-model="allocationItemSelected[index]"></allocation-item>
            </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>
```

See a runnable example clicking on codesandbox link below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-4f9xj?autoresize=1&expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&moduleview=1